# A binomial-related inequality

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

For integer $m\geq 1$, show that:
$$\sum_{|k|<\sqrt{m}}{2m \choose m+k}\geq 2^{2m-1}.$$

What I have tried:
I tried binomial expansion of $2^{2m}$ but it was unsuccessful. Any other idea?

Comment: I remember this was a good exercise for using Chebyshev's inequality.

Comment: It is only an equality when $m=1$

Comment: @xyzzyz could you please refer me to a reference?

Comment: @Henry that seems to be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, Chebyshev does the trick.

What you want to show is that when flipping $2m$ coins the probability of getting a number of heads less than $\sqrt{m}$ apart from the expected number of heads is less than $\frac{1}{2}$.

By Chebyshev the probability the outcome is more than $\sigma k$ units apart from the expected value is less than $\frac{1}{k^2}$ ( $\sigma$ is the variance of the distribution).

Note that in this case our distribution is a binomial distribution with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. So the variance is $\frac{2m}{4}=\frac{m}{2}$.

So taking $k=\frac{2}{\sqrt m}$ we get the probability the outcome is more than $\frac{m}{2}\frac{2}{\sqrt{m}}$ apart from the expected value is less than $\frac{4}{m}$. This is less than $\frac{1}{2}$ for $m\geq 8$. So we only need to try for $m=1,2,3\dots 7$ and check it out.

Comment: Why is the variance not $\frac{n}{4}$?

Comment: I think it is $2n(p)(1-p)$ and $p$ is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Fair enough: I had forgotten there are $2n$ coins rather than $n$